# Anyway to provide hint to zgrep to search part of file for faster search results

Tags: grep, logs, gzip, zgrep

Production logs file are huge in size and are stored in compressed format.

I use the following to find specific log line

```
zgrep searchString LargeLogFiles*.gz
```

Typically this takes huge amount of time, when this runs on multiple files at once.

In my case, I am aware that the **search string I'm trying to find (if present) will lie in 50% to 70% of the part of the file for sure**. Is there any way I can leverage this information for faster search?

**Possible solution**
zcat the file and filter the part using other unix commands. This is a possbility, but interested to know if there is a good/efficient way to achieve the above said problem.

Comment: @Inian Had pasted incorrect command. Updated the post with correct command that is used.

Comment: Not really. You cannot (efficiently) seek in a gzip file, unless it was compressed via a special method (`Z_FULL_FLUSH` from time to time, and add a table with the offsets -- dictionaries do that). Change your workflow to make the LargeLogFiles*.gz files smaller ;-)